# Black stripe when tool bar hide iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, toolbar

I have View with MKMapView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad]; 
   self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

   /* code of MKMapView ...*/
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```

and when I get out from this view, for a few seconds instead toolBar I see black stripe! What is this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you may try

```
 [self.navigationController setHidden:Yes animated:Yes];
```

If that doesn't do it, move the call out of this view controller. Move it to the viewWillAppear: method of the view controller that you are moving to like so

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:Yes animated:animated];
}
```

This is how I have my own and it works.

Comment: Check my edit. I remember having this issue myself and found that moving the call to the controller of the view you are moving to fixes it. I believe it is an issue with the multiple animations conflicting. You are initiating the animation of toolbar while the animation of the view is pending and so the departing view doesn't get resized in time which is why you have the black stripe.

Comment: I have not this methods                          [self.navigationController setHidden:Yes animated:animated];           I have                                           [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];        and                                                 [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];           But it's not working(((

Comment: It should be no different than self.navigationController.toolbarHidden in any case. The main thing is to take it out of the view controller you are leaving and put it into the view controller that you presenting instead.

Comment: I solved the problem.Problem was in background color in main view! Thanks for help!!